# Como inserir código de Java no html?

Tags: java, html, polyfill

Olá pessoal gostaria saber se é possível inserir código de Java no html,pois estou querendo fazer um programa de criptografia em Java mesmo e colocar dentro do html.

Estou perguntando aqui por que eu não encontrei em lugar algum sobre se é possível e como colocar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Antes não agora **sim**.

Até recentemente minha resposta seria :

> Precisa usar um applet para isso, pois você não consegue inserir o
>   Java diretamente no HTML. O suporte a applets está cada vez mais
>   restrito e em breve creio que não haverá mais suporte a applets Java
>   (são muito inseguros).

Mas... um projeto que conheci recentemente mudou minha resposta para :

> **Sim** é possível e usando JavaScript!

Esse projeto é o JavaPoly.js mais informações em https://www.javapoly.com/ .

Trata-se de uma biblioteca que permite que você tenha suporte a Java (JVM) no navegadores.

Como exemplo você pode fazer isso no HTML:

```
<!-- Include the Polyfill -->
<script src="https://www.javapoly.com/javapoly.js"></script>

<!-- Write your Java code -->
<script type="text/java">
  package com.demo;
  import com.javapoly.dom.Window;

  public class Greeter
  {
    public static void sayHello(String name)
    {
      Window.alert("Hello " + name + ", from Java!");
    }
  }
</script>

<!-- Invoke your Java code from Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  com.demo.Greeter.sayHello("world");
</script>
```

Sim, isso é Java no HTML!

Dá até para importar bibliotecas :

```
<!-- Include the Polyfill -->
<script src="https://www.javapoly.com/javapoly.js"></script>

<!-- Include your favorite Java libraries (jar files) -->
<script type="text/java" src="http://www.yourdomain.com/jimboxutilities.jar"></script>
<script type="text/java" src="http://www.yourdomain.com/guava.jar"></script>
<script type="text/java" src="http://www.yourdomain.com/apache-commons.jar"></script>

<!-- Or, include individual .class files -->
<script type="text/java" src="http://www.yourdomain.com/com/yourpackage/Foo.class"></script>
<script type="text/java" src="http://www.yourdomain.com/com/yourpackage/Noise.class"></script>

<!-- Or just include the source directly -->
<script type="text/java" src="http://www.yourdomain.com/com/yourpackage/Bar.java"></script>
<script type="text/java" src="http://www.yourdomain.com/com/yourpackage/Girls.java"></script>
```

Obs.: Nunca confundam Java com JavaScript https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/faq/java_javascript.xml.

Obs 2: Nunca usei, me parece algo recente e não sei qual o suporte ainda. Mas antes de respondermos que não dá, acho bom saber que tem gente pensando nisso.

Eis o resultado do Try It Yourself que está no site dos caras.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nem JScript com javascript...

Comment: Olá amigo,testei e não apareceu o output no navegador.

Comment: Pra mim apareceu. É leeeeeento, mas funcionou.

Comment: Abrindo a ferramenta de desenvolvedor do navegador (famoso F12) vi que ao carregar a página, após um tempo começa na janela de console a aparecer algumas mensagens como : `JVM 1 stdout> Java Main started
javapoly.js:19385 JVM 1 stdout> after bridge Active count:1
javapoly.js:19385 JVM 1 stdout> Compiling: [-d, /tmp/data, /tmp/data/com/javapoly/demo/HomepageDemo.java]` depois disso após um _lag_ consigo editar o código e clicar no botão **Compile & Run**. Ainda deve ser algo bem instável.

Comment: @Falion tente usando o Chrome e dando um tempinho para carregar o Java. Acho que os caras poderiam por um "Loading" no site.

Comment: @Falion Será que realmente compensa ter este trabalho todo ao invés de usar o javaweb, que foi feito para isso, de uma vez?

Comment: @Diego F Sim,eu preciso fazer deste jeito.

Comment: @GuilhermeJSantos Eu tentei fazer do jeito que você falou(usando o Chrome) de dar um tempo para carregar o Java e não funcionou.

Answer (score -3):

Tem  sim.  Se chama jquery.  Utiliza. As bibliotecas javascript .  Porem vc tem que. Obedecer a estrutura do código html.  Incluindo ele na. Parte da tag.  antes da  vc pode criar function e desvio de decisão com. If else. Na body vc pode chamar essas function  por click ou movimento do cursor ou carregamento da página nas div ou objeto com onkeydown=funtion()*  é super poderoso essa ferramenta e todas as sua  compatível com html5 compatível com Chrome  mas algumas funções funcionam tambem no IE9.
Vc pode utilizar para facilitar o bootstrap q tbm utiliza bastante javascript

*nome da function a ser usada.

Comment: Ola joao, bem vindo à comunidade do SO-Pt. Na pergunta ele se refere à JAVA. O jQuery por sua vez é para JavaScript (EcmaScript). Fácil de confundir, mas são coisas extremamente diferentes.